# Media Foundation Write Sample gives Access Violation while writing

Tags: c#, c++, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--using-the-sink-writer-to-encode-video.

I followed this Documentation and tried to create a video sample using a few  bitmapImages . However after the below line there is a Exception.

The Bitmap Image is sent to the WriteFrame() function of format byte [] array format which is similar to VideosourceFrame but in DWORD format  in the tutorial.

```
pSinkWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, spSample));
```

The Exception after this line is

```
     Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCE9A9DF33 (ntdll.dll) in Movie.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024.
```

The run time values of the writer, sample, buffer : just before the Exception

[image: Media Buffer]

[image: Media sample]

[image: Media SinkWriter]
[callstack after the call to Writesample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEH40.png)

Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Post a minimal example which reproduces the error.

Comment: `spSample` is probably null

Comment: For instance, the Parameters of the WriteFrame (array<byte>^ videoFrameBuffer, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) 
 this VideoFrambuffer is used in CHK(MFCopyImage(pbBuffer,
  cbWidth,(BYTE *) videoFrameBuffer.ToPointer(), cbWidth, cbWidth, imageHeight));

Copy happens without a Issue, but after this I added the buffer to sample and set length and the duration of it .

Then when  this API  is called pSinkWriter->WriteSample(streamIndex, spSample));

This Exception is thrown Exception thrown at 0x00007FF (ntdll.dll) in Movie.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location

Comment: SpSample added the pbbuffer (Result From the MFCopyImage) without any issue.
Is there any way to check if it null or not and confirm what all should go wrong?

Comment: System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
This is the Exact Exception

Comment: Means some code is trying to write to pointer with address 0x24 (36). It could be a hint, as obviously it's not a rogue address or it's not an address where memory has been deallocated (which is a common cause of issue, especially with garbage collectors and unpinned memory...). It's really a wrong pointer. You can try to uncheck "Enable just my code" in VS' Tools/Options/Debugging with symbols enabled you should have a stack including Windows dlls. Could give you other hints

Comment: We don't know what is exactly in `spSample`. No buffer attached? Wrong data there? Mismatching to media type you previously used to set up the writer? You need to debug and attach this to the question, we can't guess.

Comment: @RomanR.. i have attached the Run time value of the spsample and spbuffer. Would it help .?